# Google Docs document in Hebrew and English?

Tags: localization, google-docs

Is there any way to have Hebrew and English in the same document in Google Docs?

So far, everything I have found about multiple languages seems to assume that you want the user interface (menus, etc) and document text in the same language, and that you only want that one language.  I would like the interface to stay in English but let me type Hebrew and English into the document text.

Comment: Did the answer fit for question?

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes!

Assuming you have a second language installed on your machine, you should simply be able to toggle to it normally. According to my experience Google Docs will automatically support it if your OS does. You can toggle back and forth at will (usually `Cmd+Space` on Mac, `Alt+Shift` on Windows, and `user-defined` on Linux) as you would in any other document.

Answer (score 1):

The user interface language (of the 'system') for Google Documents is set in Google Drive (Settings > Language), though that is the one you should not need to adjust (*I would like the interface to stay in English*).

The language of the document itself (of the 'file') is set within the document in Language under the File menu, where `עברית` is one of *many* options.